# How can I overflow hidden on one side only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webflow

I'm building a website on Webflow and what should be a quick section to build in now driving me crazy. I have a flexbox container that has 2 divs in it. The left div is an "about us" section and the right is a slider with a few photos about 30px apart. I want the slider to overflow off the right side of the page, but when I have overflow off the slide covers the about section on the left when clicked. I've been searching for custom CSS or jquery to hide overflow on one side only but I can't find anything.

Comment: Please provide some [minimal-reproducible-code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please provide what CSS you have already tried and as Keshav said, please provide a minimal reproducible code. You can use codepen.io for the code.

Comment: Please provide related chunk of code in order to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow, sadly enough, can't be set on one side only. At least in most cases.
`Overflow-x:hidden` automatically sets `overflow-y:hidden`.

You have to code your way around it. Have you tried playing around with z-index?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried z-index, absolute positioning divs under the about me but above the slider. It's just a mess lol. I'm not really a coder but I understand it enough. I was hoping someone could share custom code that I can add with jquery or css that could do the trick,

Comment: Do you have any examples? Your code and HTML or even a screenshot would be immensely helpful.
In my case, i had a scrollable topnav (with a custom scrollbar) and needed a way to get the dropdowns to be visible under the container.

My solution was to move the dropdowns to the body element, absolutely position them and add position with a few lines of code, based on the related nav item element.

In your case, maybe you could throw a mask on the whole thing. See this link:
[link]https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/